# После начала установки Windows на экране появляются помехи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Tags: windows-10, установка

Когда начинается установка Windows, на экране появляются помехи. Что делать в этой ситуации?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы нашли решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Подозреваю, что менять/чинить видеокарту...

Comment: Это не похоже на "после переустановки", больше похоже на проблему с "железом". Что делать - нести в сервис.